# How to run the react app without a server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created the project using **npx create-react-app my-app** https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app.

When running **npm run build** I get the following:

> 70.28 KB         build\static\js\2.93539f7c.chunk.js
>     22.82 KB         build\static\css\main.cfe0ffe9.chunk.css
>     1.41 KB (+44 B)  build\static\js\main.79f4d9a1.chunk.js   761 B            build\static\js\runtime~main.fdfcfda2.js
>
> The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root. You
>   can control this with the homepage field in your package.json. For
>   example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:

Looks like I need to have server to run the app.

Is it possible to run this locally without any server running? I mean since it is just html,css,js and why would a server be needed here? for what purpose?

Also there is many files generated into the build folder, there is an index.html too, a static folder, so its not like a single bundle.js and a single index.html, it seems more complicated.

Anyone can explain why the build folder is this much files? and which one to consider for running the app?

Thanks

Comment: Use `npm start`.

Comment: i mean i want to use the production mode, so all files optimized, npm start would start the development mode.

Comment: Depends, If you want to access files relatively you need a server.

Comment: @RajendrakumarVankadari im not sure i understood you, what do you mean by accessing files relatively? can you be more concrete? Also woudlnt I be able to run html, css and js without any server?

Comment: yes, you need a web server to publish a website.

Comment: so its not possible for example have these files locally and call the index.html from an android webview? so basiacally the whole build folder would live inside an android app.

Comment: so let me make it clear, is is mandatory for me to host it somewhere on internet in order to run this react app?

Comment: also why there are two different js files inside build/js/? its like some hashcode.chunk.js and main.hashcode.chunk.js also there is a runtime~main.hashcode.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to run this locally without any server running?

No

> I mean since it is just html,css,js and why would a server be needed here? for what purpose?

React loads content using XHR, which can't make requests to file scheme URLs.

> Anyone can explain why the build folder is this much files?

React makes use of code chunking to optimise which data is loaded. This means that JS which isn't used immediately can be loaded later on and not impact the time between initial page load and first render.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Create React App produces a build assuming your app is hosted at the server root.
To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json, for example:

`"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath"`

This will let Create React App correctly infer the root path to use in the generated HTML file.

source: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

So you should just specify your homepage as the current path:

`"homepage": "./"`